# How can I handle error while executing remote command in linux

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am currently creating a class to execute command remotely on a linux machine using ssh(paramiko). The following is the code I am using

```
def connect(self):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(self.ip, port=self.port, username=self.user,password=self.password,timeout=self.timeout)
    time.sleep(10)
    return ssh

def runCommands(self,commands):
    ssh=self.connect()
    channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
    time.sleep(10)
    for command in commands:
        wait=0
        while channel.send_ready()!=True:
            wait+=1
            time.sleep(self.timeout)
            if wait==5:
                return 0
        channel.send(command+'\n')
    channel.send("exit\n")
    return 1
```

My question here is if the command run into an error for example if I use 'mkdir a': "file exist error" is encountered, How can I handle it. I tried using channel.recv(buff_size) but the problem here is I could not differentiate between error and normal messages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`channel.recv_exit_status()` can be used to get the return code of the command executed. You can refer to [this paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv_exit_status) documentation.